# Desativar disabled do form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho esta função, onde ele verifica os dados, para sair da página, o que acontece que alguns dados ficam como `disabled` conforme os dados informados, e não consigo verificar os dados.

```
  $(function () {
    var init_form = $('#Novo').serialize();
    $(':submit').click(function () { window.onbeforeunload = null; });

        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        var check_form = $('#Novo').serialize();
        console.log(init_form);
        console.log(check_form);
        if (check_form === init_form) return null;
        return 'Os dados do formulário não foram salvos, deseja permanecer nesta página?';
    };
});
```

Tentei adicionar esta linha no método `$("#Novo :input").prop('disabled', false);` porém também não deu certo.

```
 $(function () {
    var init_form = $('#Novo').serialize();
    $(':submit').click(function () { window.onbeforeunload = null; });
         $("#Novo :input").prop('disabled', false);
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        var check_form = $('#Novo').serialize();
        console.log(init_form);
        console.log(check_form);
        if (check_form === init_form) return null;
        return 'Os dados do formulário não foram salvos, deseja permanecer nesta página?';
    };
});
```

Como posso fazer para que todos os dados sejam verificados, independente se a propriedade `disabled` ou `readonly` estiver como `true`.

Comment: Mas se vc desativar os disabled dos inputs e o usuário cancelar o beforeunload, esses inputs ficarão ativos. Não ficaria estranho?

Comment: Tentou por o `$("#Novo :input").prop('disabled', false);` dentro da função `onbeforeunload` ?

Comment: Existe alguma maneira de "burlar" isso, coloquei como `readonly` mas mesmo assim, alguns ainda não aparece na comparação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função auxiliar que irá recuperar os dados dos inputs desabilitados e assim não precisando desabilitar nenhum campo, pois a função `serialize()` não recupera esses dados, segue o exemplo a abaixo.

```
$(function () {
    var init_form = $('#Novo').serialize();
    $(':submit').click(function () { window.onbeforeunload = null; });
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {

        // Variável que irá guardar os dados de inputs disabilitados
        var inputsDisabled = InputsDisabled('#Novo');

        var check_form = $('#Novo').serialize() + inputsDisabled;
        console.log(init_form);
        console.log(check_form);
        if (check_form === init_form) return null;
        console.log('Os dados do formulário não foram salvos, deseja permanecer nesta página?');
        return false;
    };
});
```

Função para recuperar os campos disabilitados

```
function InputsDisabled(form) {
    const input = $(`${form} input:disabled`);
    let params = '';
    $.each(input, function (key, val) {
        params += `&${val.name}=${val.value}`;
    });
    return params;
}
```